# in Applescript, can you add an item to the left menu bar if you’re creating an app?

Tags: menu, applescript

Hello I’m Tate and I have a Question.In applescript, can you create an item for the left menu (application menu) on mac that is not already there by default? if you know the answer, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to add menu items to the application menu bar, but you might check into [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), which offers the ability to customize a script menu with whatever order of scripts you like and with keyboard shortcuts. It's free for any number of scripts and up to 10 keyboard shortcuts.

Also, although I've never used it, [ThisService](http://wafflesoftware.net/thisservice/) apparently allows you to use AppleScript to add items to the Services menu in the application menu. You might check it out also.

Answer (score 0):

Automator can save Applescripts so that they show up in the Services menu in each Application menu.  Just run Automator, create and Applescript workflow and save it as a service.  You can assign a command key to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't simple, but is possible. Following script should be saved and executed as **stay-open application**.

```
-- script: Creating Menus example for AsObjC applications
-- written: by KniazidisR, 19 Sep 2022 17:10:25

-- IMPORTANT: save and run this script as Stay-Open application
-- If you will execute the script as is from Script Editor of Script Debugger,
-- it will erase its menu items. Only after restarting the script editor
-- the menu items will restore. smile 

use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"


-- init new menu bar to build menus from scratch
set menubar to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s init()

-- clear predefined menus
set menuBarItem to current application's NSMenuItem's new()
menubar's addItem:menuBarItem
current application's NSApp's setMainMenu:menubar
current application's NSApp's mainMenu()'s removeAllItems()

-- make and edit App name's menu 
set asstMenuItem to menubar's addItemWithTitle:"" action:(missing value) keyEquivalent:""
set asstMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s init()
menubar's setSubmenu:asstMenu forItem:asstMenuItem
set preferencesMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Preferences" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:""
(preferencesMenuItem's setTarget:me)
set quitMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Quit" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"q"
(quitMenuItem's setTarget:me)

-- make and edit "File" menu 
set asstMenuItem to menubar's addItemWithTitle:"" action:(missing value) keyEquivalent:""
set asstMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s initWithTitle:"File"
menubar's setSubmenu:asstMenu forItem:asstMenuItem
set openMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Open" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"o"
(openMenuItem's setTarget:me)
set saveMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Save" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"s"
(saveMenuItem's setTarget:me)
set saveAsMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Save As..." action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"a"
(saveAsMenuItem's setTarget:me)
set printMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Print..." action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"p"
(printMenuItem's setTarget:me)

-- make and edit "Edit" menu
set asstMenuItem to menubar's addItemWithTitle:"" action:(missing value) keyEquivalent:""
set asstMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s initWithTitle:"Edit"
menubar's setSubmenu:asstMenu forItem:asstMenuItem
set openMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Copy" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"c"
(openMenuItem's setTarget:me)
set saveMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Paste" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"v"
(saveMenuItem's setTarget:me)
set saveAsMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Undo" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"u"
(saveAsMenuItem's setTarget:me)
set printMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Redo" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"r"
(printMenuItem's setTarget:me)


on actionHandler:sender
    set theTitle to title of sender as string
    if theTitle is "Quit" then quit
    display dialog "The \"" & theTitle & "\" menu item pressed"
end actionHandler:
```